# React.createElement type invalid

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: . Did you accidentally
>   export a JSX literal instead of a component?

I have `LazyLoading` component :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const LazyLoadingComponent = (
  {
    resolve,
    ...restProps
  }
) => {
  const [module, setModule] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    resolve().then((module) => {
      const View = module.default
      setModule(<View {...restProps} />)
    })
  }, [resolve])
  return (
    module && module
  )
}

LazyLoadingComponent.propTypes = {
  resolve: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default LazyLoadingComponent
```

I have an `object` which I pass by using props to another component :

```
export const player = (params, intl) => {
  const symbol = addSymbol(params)

  return {
    pathname: sidebar.playersPathname,
    name: intl.formatMessage(messages.playerHeaderName),
    svg: <AccountCircle />,
    buttons: [
      {
        name: intl.formatMessage(messages.createPlayerButtonName),
        pathname: `${symbol}dialog=${dialogs.playerCreate}`
      }
    ],
    extensionPanel: [
      {
        name: sidebar.playersSearch,
        isExpanded: false,
        component: <LazyLoading resolve={() => import('components/Menu/ExpansionPanels/General/PlayerSearch')} />,
        subMenus: []
      },
      {
        name: sidebar.editPlayer,
        isExpanded: false,
        component: <LazyLoading resolve={() => import('components/Menu/ExpansionPanels/General/Summary')} />,
        subMenus: []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And I have some element in which I want to show this `LazyLoading` component and pass to this component some additional props :

```
<div>
  {
      React.craeteElement(data.component,{
          menuState,
          open: params.name === data.name
       })
   }
</div>
```

But when I do it , I get issue which you can see above. Is it possible do the same what I want by using another working case ?

If it isn't clear :

```
component: <LazyLoading resolve={() => import('components/Menu/ExpansionPanels/General/PlayerSearch')} />,
```

This property related with `data.component` in `React.createElement` by which error occur

and also see how `data.component` looks in `console.log(data.component)` :
[image]

**components/Menu/ExpansionPanels/General/PlayerSearch :**

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import messages from '../messages'

import Search from '@material-ui/icons/Search'
import ArrowRight from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowRight'

import compose from 'hoc/compose'
import withIntl from 'hoc/withIntl'

import General from 'components/Menu/ExpansionPanels/General'

function PlayerSearch (
  {
    intl,
    open,
    menuState
  }
) {
  return (
    <General
      search={<Search />}
      message={intl.formatMessage(messages.playerSearch)}
      arrow={<ArrowRight />}
      open={open}
      menuState={menuState}
    />
  )
}

PlayerSearch.propTypes = {
  intl: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  menuState: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}

export default compose(
  withIntl()
)(PlayerSearch)
```

Comment: What is extension of PlayerSearch file js or jsx ?

Comment: I attached this info . Pls check it